# Android: Changing dalvik.vm.heapsize past a certain value results in getting stuck on Android boot screen

Tags: android

I am running an Android VM with Virtualbox. I have system read/write access and I want to increase the dalvik.vm.heapsize to 2048m from 512m. Anything over 576m results in Android getting stuck on the boot screen.

I have given the VM 16GB of RAM and 4 processors. Can it just not run with that large of a heapsize or do I need to change some of the other build properties along with the change I have made?

Comment: I guess I should say that I am using android-x86_64-7.1-r5.iso

Comment: Which version of android are you using? Can you please share the platform build which your device has?

Comment: @TomTaylor I said the build in the comment above. It is Android 25